# Composite mist pass after-the-fact to finished rendered video using the original blend

Tags: compositing-nodes

Say you have 500 stills comprising a video, and you also have the original blend file that created the stills. Is there a way to do a render that skips the time-consuming Image pass but still provides various other passes (like Mist, Shadow, etc.)? And such that those passes are stored in a way that can be input to the compositor to apply the result to the stills? I have done very skimpy passes (low bounces, etc.) that sort of achieve this, and stored them as multilayer EXRs, but haven't found a way to apply the output to more than one frame at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to do this is as you said: low bounces, no caustics, etc.

You can bring the already rendered image sequences into the compositor with the [*image*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Input#Image_node) node:

1. Add an image node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Input > Image*)
2. Open the first frame of your image sequence in the image node
3. Change the source type to *Image Sequence*:

   [image]
4. Set the *Frames*, *Offset* and *Start frame* values.

   - *Frames* is the number of frames to use.
   - *Start frame* is the scene frame on which to display the first frame
   - *Offset* is the amount to offset the current frame. (e.g. with *Offset* = `5`, the image for frame 6 will be read instead of the image for frame 1)

You can load your sequence of *Multilayer* images alongside your original render into the compositor in this fashion. If you rendered the *Multilayer* images with the render passes enabled you should be able to use the passes from the *Image* node.

You can also use this alongside the *Renderlayer* node to composite with the render directly, e.g. with a `150` frame image sequence:

[image]

Comment: gandalf3 - Thanks, then I guess that really is as good as it gets. I was hoping for a way to do both 1) Run the PNG/JPEG file Image Sequence side-by-side with the live animation render 2) completely turn-off the main RGB pass in the animation render while still doing other passes that don't require it. The lesson I take from this: Always render to multilayer EXRs with as many passes checked-off as you could conceivably regret missing :)

Comment: @PlenusFranckly It's possible the disable to RGB (combined) pass, however this is pointless as cycles still needs to path trace the scene to generate a result for the other passes (to prove this try disabling *Use surfaces* in the renderlayers panel, all the passes will have no data.) you want, which takes the same amount of time as it would otherwise. In other words, to get a rendered pass, you need to render it. As for 1, if I understand correctly, you should be able to do that with the image sequence node. Have you tried it?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, I've been able to composite a PNG image sequence side-by-side with a multilayer EXR sequence; the approach that didn't work was running the PNG image sequence concurrently with "live frames" from the Render Layers output (what I meant by "live animation render"). I can do one-frame-at-a-time, but not batch. I was interested only because it seemed like a more flexible approach, since I could play with just how many bounces & samples i could do-away-with to still get convincing mist.

Comment: @PlenusFranckly Hmm.. It should work.. See my edit.